# Informing people about genealogy services offered?

Tags: discussion

Without breaking any rules, how can I inform people that I can provide genealogical research in a country which has few records online, and most only available at the archives?

Unless people can actually travel there themselves, those records are out of reach.

Comment: Advertising your services directly is not permitted so I am going to migrate your question to our Meta site for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The way to indirectly advertise your services is to ask and answer questions on our Main site so that you can develop a reputation that entices people to visit [your user card](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6298/strazy) where you are free to describe the services that you offer.

Take care that your questions and answers do not themselves constitute advertisements in any way.

Comment: May I ask why is this? If for example someone is searching ancestors from a place that I already have digital copies of or may travel to an archive to get those records? Wouldn't that be easier? And if there are more than one offering their services, the person in need may choose their best option. Sorry if I am wrong. Or do you think that someone would get information online for free and try to sell it to others?

Comment: @Strazy it sounded to me like you wanted to advertise your services which is not permitted unless you purchase advertising using a button at the bottom of each page. It is not cheap to do that. What you can do on this site is to ask, answer and (once you get 50 rep) comment anywhere but those three functions must not include advertisements within them. If you aim to answer questions using your own records that is is fine and the community will soon let you know if you appear to be posting thinly veiled adverts.

Comment: @Strazy This [Romania question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12821) could be a good place for you to showcase your skills and services. At the moment it is very vague, but I wonder if you might be able to provide any suggestions about the research process of searching for an ancestor's grave in Romania. I don't even know what records might be available in Romania as far as burial or cemetery registers, plot books, memorial inscriptions, etc. and where someone might go to find them?

Comment: @Strazy I'm not sure if we have any Romania experts on the site so it would be great if you stick around and ask and answer a few questions on the subject! We actually have a fair number of [unanswered Romania questions](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romania?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50) which you might be able to help with.